# R - stack or melt dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, network-analysis

i need to do network analysis of tweets and got following Dataframe:

```
 # A tibble: 10 x 3
   Screen.name    party  mentions                                                               
    <chr>          <chr>  <chr>                                                                  
 1 @_A_K_K_       CDU    ""                                                                     
 2 @A_Gloeckner   SPD    "@MartinSchulz @MartinSchulz @MartinSchulz @ManuelaSchwesig @sigmargab~
 3 @a_grotheer    SPD    "@NSC_CPMR @SouthendRNLI @weserkurier @werderbremen @ribasdiego10 @boe~
 4 @A_Schillhane~ GRUENE "@BA_Mitte_Berlin @nytimes @nutellaberliner @Flauschpolizei @A_Schillh~
 5 @Achim_P       SPD    "@spdmilk @Achim_P @jusosowl @FranzmannMarcel @KorkmazGT @c_kampmann @~
 6 @AdolfKessel1  CDU    "@CDUFraktionRLP @AdolfKessel1"                                        
 7 @AfDLindemann  AfD    "@welt @BVG_Kampagne @SeeroiberJenny @spdde @AfDBerlin @spdberlin @See~
 8 @AfdMatzke     AfD    "@APVogt @AfdMatzkeNicht @Leyla_eV @COMPACTMagazin @BjoernHoecke @Birg~
 9 @agnieszka_mdb GRUENE "@HelgeBoettcher @agnieszka_mdb @MV_AM @agnieszka_mdb @larscastellucci~
10 @alex_gauland  AfD    "@RT_Dyck @extra3 @RT_Deutsch @_Herzblatt_ @m_shalva @FraukePetry @Meu~
```

To go on with my network analysis, i need my Dataframe to look as follows:

```
    Screen.name    mentions            party
  1 @A_Gloeckner   @MartinSchulz       SPD
  2 @A_Gloeckner   @MartinSchulz       SPD
  3 @A_Gloeckner   @MartinSchulz       SPD
  4 @A_Gloeckner   @ManuelaSchwesig    SPD
  5 @A_Gloeckner   @sigmargabriel      SPD
  6 @a_grotheer    @NSC_CPMR           SPD
  7 @a_grotheer    @SouthendRNLI       SPD
  8 @a_grotheer    @weserkurier        SPD
  9 @a_grotheer    @werderbremen       SPD
     ...           ...
```

I tried melting or stacking the dataframe, but this hasn't worked:

```
test <- ds %>%
  select(Screen.name, mentions)
test <- melt(test, id=c("Screen.name"))
# other approach
test <- stack(ds[,c(1,3)])
```

Both approaches giving me the wrong output.
A bonus would also be to include the specific "party" here. I am also open to other solution for network analysis here but this kind of dataframe seems to be helpful to create a graph out of it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `melt` and `stack` are for melting multiple value columns into a single value column (eg. wide to long format) and `stack` is the opposite. Your data contains a single `string` column that you want to `split` and combine into rows. This is neither stack nor melt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, if you want to stick in tidyverse, you can use `str_split` from `stringr` to split the column of strings into character vectors of occurences (the new column becomes a list column), and then use `unnest_longer` to unnest this result.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mentionsplit = str_split(mentions, '\\s')) %>% 
  unnest_longer(mentionsplit)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was:

```
s <- strsplit(ds$mentions, split = " ")
df <- data.frame(Screen.name = rep(ds$Screen.name, sapply(s, length)),mentions = unlist(s))
```